# Validation message tokens no longer being replaced in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Something happened in my Rails app today, and now all of my validation errors are appearing like this, without all of the tokens replaced.  I have no idea what I could've done, I've tried rebooting, switching branches, and rolling my code back to previous versions.

```
{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:

    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
```

Comment: If you've tried all the thing you mentioned it might be a gem problem.  Did you do a `gem update` and now you're using a new version of rails or another plugin you require?

Comment: I did start doing a `gem update` and then had second thoughts about it trying to go and update all my gems (which could be bad), so I Ctrl-C'd out of it.  Maybe I left it in limbo or something.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I ended up with two versions of the activemodel gem installed, 2.3.5 (for Rails 2.3.5, which we are running) and 3.0.3.  Once I uninstalled activemodel 3.0.3, things were back to normal.